# Two equivalent definitions of recurrent states in Markov Chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I am learning about the classification of states in Markov chain, and confused about two definitions of recurrent states.

**State i is recurrent if 'starting from i, and from wherever you can go, there is a way of returning to i '**

This one is quite intuitive, and under some circumstances quite convenient.

Another one is defining by the first pass shown as

**State i is recurrent if '
$f_{ij} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} fij^{(n)} = 1$, where $fij^{(n)}$ denotes the probability of $(X_{n} = j,X_{m} \neq j,m = 1,2,\dots,n-1|X_{0} = i)$'**

Can anyone show me the equivalence of these two definitions?

Answer (score 2):

$f_{ij}$ is exactly your first definition, quantified mathematically.  To see this, observe that
\begin{align*}
f_{ij} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} f_{ij}^{(n)} &= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}\{X_{n} = j, \, \, X_{m} \neq j \, \, \text{for} \, \, j \in \{1,2,\dots,n-1\} \, \mid \, X_{0} = i\} \\
&= \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} \{X_{n} = j, \, \, X_{m} \neq j \, \, \text{for} \, \, j \in \{1,2,\dots,n-1\} \, \mid \, X_{0} = i \right) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left( \{X_{n} = j \, \, \text{for some} \, \, j \geq 1 \} \, \mid \, X_{0} = i \right)
\end{align*}
Hence, given $i,j$, the Markov chain $\{X_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ started at $i$ "hits" $j$ with probability $1$ if and only if $f_{ij} = 1$.